# Is it possible to use GIT to manage clients licences?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

We've got an application that is installed on dozens clients servers. Clients pay us a periodic fee to keep the application up to date. We use GIT to manage all files on clients hosts and to update we use just `git pull` command.

Anyway, there is a case that some client stopped pay us for updates. So we don't want him to use `git pull` and download latests files when he actually shouldn't.

So we're looking now for some method to control cases like this one. We're wondering if is it possible to tell remote GIT repository that the latests commit we're able to get is for example from the April 2017? Is it possible to pass to GIT repository some kind of license key to do that?

If it's not possible with GIT, is there any other solutions for this?

Big thanks for your help!

Comment: I guess when they do a pull they are using a username, so you can just disallow this user, but then he loses the complete access.

Comment: As @MartinVerjans says, simply remove their access to the repository they pull from. Invalidate/delete/block the user they're using and they cannot download more updates.

Answer (score 0):

Just off the top of my head:

Do all of your clients use the same remote address to receive updates via `git pull`?
If so, then I would change it so that each client has their own unique address. Controlling who has access to the latest update is then a matter of whether or not you have synced their repository with the master application repository.